# Android res/layout Folder not included in the APK file

Tags: apache-flex, apk

I am buildeing flex app with android native extension 
but my apk does not contain the layout folder 
so when i call the native mathod of android lib which call a activity of android 
as given direction by [Launching new activity from an ANE](http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=3119#comment-773092)

then
Getting error while using `inte.putExtra(“layout”, adec.getResourceId(“layout.second”));`
Error says:`Resourse not found`

is it problem ocuurring while building ANE or apk .

Answer (score 0):

while building the .ane you should make sure that the "res" folder is included. check this out: [Adobe AIR 3 native extensions - Android res folder not included in the .ane file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060041/adobe-air-3-native-extensions-android-res-folder-not-included-in-the-ane-file)